# Constrained Set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Developing some parts of a project I needed to implement a data set like structure which should allow me to get subsets depending on a minimun-maximun key value:

```
ConstainedSet <- Set((key,value)*)
Subset <- ConstainedSet.Match(Constraint = "val1 <= key < val2")
```

Then *Subset* should only containt those elements from *ConstainedSet* matching the "val1 <= key < val2" restriction. That is, those elements whose key is greater or equal than *val1* but lesser than *val2*.

For example, If we had a subset like this one:

```
ConstrainedSet <- {(1,hand),(2,eye),(3,nose)}
```

Then an operation like:

```
Subset <- ConstainedSet.Match(Constraint = "1 <= key < 3")
```

Ought result generate this Subset:

```
Subset <- {(1,hand),(2,eye)}
```

I developed a solution where each element is stored in a vector of triplets like

```
(minKey,maxKey+1,value)
```

I keep this vector sorted by *minKey* and *maxKey* having *minKey* order a higher priority than *maxKey* order. Then each call to "Match" performs a binary search over this vector.

If I am not wrong worst case time complexities are:

- O(N) for each call to "Match".
- O(N) for insertions.

Where N is the number of elements in the set.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: both operations will be O(Log(N))

Comment: @CapelliC I thought so but then I recalled that match may return more than one element, if the constraint match all set elements then you have to copy into Subset all ConstrainedSet elements which takes O(N). So total worst case complexity is O(Log(N))+O(N) = O(N). Concerning insertions, once you have found where the new entry should be you'll probably have to move upper elements so I think I have O(N) too. I will edit my question.

Comment: maybe I don't understand the problem. Usually sets don't allow duplicates, then how we could match more than 1 element ?

Comment: @CapelliC Match result is a subset not an element.

Comment: Does "higher priority" here mean you sort first by minKey, then maxKey?

Comment: If all `N` elements can be returned, it would be impossible to beat `O(N)`, since you can't return an element in less than `O(1)`. You can and should define complexity in terms of number of elements in the output set, i.e. `O(f(M,N))` where `M` is the number of items returned.

Comment: Wait, what's `minKey` and `maxKey` here? The given constraints? Isn't that independent of the element? Why are you sorting by it?

Comment: @Dukeling Constraint <- minKey <= key <= maxKey

Comment: As I understand the question (at least up to your approach), you've got a set of `(key,value)` pairs. Then you're given one `(minKey, maxKey)` pair, and you have to find all values where the key matches. Where do multiple `(minKey, maxKey)` pairs come in? If you generate them yourself, how do you do this? By the way, if I understood correctly, [Karoly's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18986708/1711796) is perfect.

Comment: @Dukeling I think this example may clarify the question: Think of a SQL database where you have a table with a column 'X' then you want to show all rows whose column 'X' is between a lower and an upper bound. This is the same but for a data structure in memory instead a database.

Comment: So I do understand correctly, but I still don't understand where multiple `(minKey, maxKey)` pairs come in.

Comment: @Dukeling I am sorry but my example wasn't complete. Each element doesn't have only a key associated but an interval. These date interval never overlap. That's is why the key has two elements (min and max).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in a balanced binary tree by the key.

Lookup, Insertion: O(log n).

If you have to copy the results, that's always going to be O(n), but if no copy is needed the subset can be represented by a pair of "iterators", you can return a pair of min and max nodes from the tree, so the whole thing is going to be O(log n).